# In-app purchases to unlock paid functions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am looking to release two version of my app: free and paid. The paid app will have a few more functions but no extra content as such. Originally I was going to release two separate apps on the market but it is proving difficult to keep a single code base and have two separate apps.

Would in-app purchases be a better way to do this? So I release a free app and then allow users to purchase a unlock for the extra functions. This would also mean that I wouldn't have to explicitly use the licensing part of the Android development as that is taken care of within the in-app purchasing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are three strategies which come to my mind:

1. **Release two versions, a free version and a paid version. The paid version contains additional features.** To make development easier, you should use [Android Libaries](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects). These prevent the duplication of code.

**Advantages:**

- Simpler to implement.
- Works on other markets as the Android Market because it is not dependant on it.

**Disadvantage:**

- If the user has some data in the free version, you must provide a import functionality for the paid version or the user will loose the data.
- You have two versions on the market which get different reviews.

2. **Release App + Unlock App: a free version which contains all features but some features are locked. Unlock them using a "unlock app" which is a simple paid app released on the market.**

**Advantages:**

- Simple to implement.
- Works on other markets as the Android Market because it is not dependant on it.

**Disadvantes:**

- Is not that intuitive because the user has a "useless" app installed.

3. **Release one version: a free version which contains all features but some features are locked. Unlock them using in-app purchases.**

**Advantages:**

- Finegrained solution: You can unlock different features for different prices.

**Disadvantes:**

- Not that simple to implement, the In-App-API is tricky
- Does not work without Android Market

Comment: +1. I think you should also include something about which one of the options you recommend. Would make the answer more complete.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete response. My research has shown more problems than those mentioned above though. Version 1 does not allow for different functionality (activities), only resources can be over-written. Version 2 does not allow for use of Google's licensing servers. Version 3 is what I am thinking about at the moment. Anyway, thank you for your effort.

Comment: (1) "free and paid based on library project" has a big disadvantage: two applications cannot provide the same `ContentProvider`

Comment: point 2 has an additional disadvantage which is "You have to versions on the market which get different reviews."

Answer (score 1):

You could also use two separate flavors.
One for the free version and the other for the paid version.
Without rewriting another boss project.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html