# In app-billing implementation , buying paid app from free version

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have paid and free version application in the single publisher account. now I have implemented the in-app billing implementation in free version I have added the in app product and done implementation in application code also. But what I want is user should able to buy the paid app from the free version app using the in app billing purchase. I am not getting how to add paid app as in app product and paid app get downloaded once user purchase the paid version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not add any other app like "in-app purchase". In your case there is two possibilities:

1. [Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964819/start-android-market-from-app) user to market. In this case you have to provide sharing data between apps (like progress in a game or something, that was done in free version)
2. You can provide all possibilities in "free" version, and lock it, while user does not buy "unlock full version" purchase.

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170466/in-app-purchases-to-unlock-paid-functions).